# How to add an application from the Azure AD Gallery Programmatically

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

How do I add an application from the AAD Gallery programmatically and configure it? I checked AAD Powershell commands but I could not find out how to use it to provision a pre-integrated applications from the Azure AD gallery. There is the  **New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication"** for example but not an Add-AzureRmADApplication or similar. The application I need is already available under the "Developer Services" category in the AAD Applications Gallery and all I need is to add it and configure its **Single-sign on** and **Provisioning** attributes. Is that even possible or do I have to create a new app? Even if I created a new application how do I configure it past the just adding the HomePage and IdentifierUris parameters which is all I can do using the New-AzureRmADApplication cmndlt?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You might be able to define the deployment using an ARM template then deploy the ARM template from powershell using `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: If I had an answer I would post an answer. It was just a comment to asses whether you've abandoned the question and how interested you are in solving your own issue.

Comment: There are already Azure AD cmndlets to create a new application $ New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication" The issue is that I cannot configure it beyond the few cmdlet options that are available. For example, I want to set certain settings under Single sign-on (eg. the sign-on mode, user attributes for a SAML sign-on mode, etc), and Provisioning settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-4.4.1

Comment: You need to create a *service principal* not an application. Check the cmdlets for creating service principals.

Comment: @juunas thanks for the reply but can you elaborate on how creating a service principle going to help me add an application from the Azure AD Gallery and configure it say using Azure Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to configure the applications from the AAD Application Gallery programmatically. You can refer to the following post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42f262e2-150e-48bd-a741-cbabf42fcf77/how-to-add-and-configure-aad-application-from-the-gallery-programatically?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone come's across this question again, this is now possible, with the AzVm modules, instead of AzRm.

First you get the "Gallery Application Version"

```
$galleryApp = Get-AzGalleryApplicationVersion -GalleryName $GalleryName `
                        -GalleryApplicationName $AppName `
                        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

Then create a new app instance for your current PowerShell Session

```
$appInstance = New-GalleryApplication -PackageReferenceId $galleryApp.Id
```

You'll also need to set the order parameter after you create the instance. There's no parameter to set it when it's defined.

```
$appInstance.Order = $int32Value
```

Finally, add the application to your Virtual Machine

```
Add-AzVmGalleryApplication -VM $VirtualMachineObjet `
                       -GalleryApplication $appInstance
                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

Once the application(s) are added, you need to push the update with "Update-AzVm", otherwise they won't actually deploy.

Here's the full example:

```
$galleryApp = Get-AzGalleryApplicationVersion -GalleryName $GalleryName `
                        -GalleryApplicationName $AppName `
                        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

$appInstance = New-GalleryApplication -PackageReferenceId $galleryApp.Id
$appInstance.Order = $int32Value

Add-AzVmGalleryApplication -VM $VirtualMachineObjet `
                   -GalleryApplication $appInstance `
                   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                   -Order $int32Value

Update-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VM $VirtualMachineObject
```